# I need to get and set text in JTextField, that I created using a for loop, usign a JButton

Tags: java, for-loop, jbutton, jtextfield

I created these fields on a container called ct and using a grid bag constraints called cons

```
for(int x=0;x<5;x++)
{
  JTextField txtDetails = new JTextField(" ");
  cons.gridx = 1; cons.gridy = x+1;
  cons.gridwidth = 1;
  ct.add(txtDetails, cons);
 }
```

I am using an action listener so I can use buttons to interact with the form I created, I want to be able to clear all the fields and get the text from each text field one by one but I'm stuck.

Usually I would create the textfields individually with their own unique name but this time I want to try it like this to save me from writing basically the same code five times

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to store your TetFields in a dynamic datastructure such as a Map, Set or List?. Then you could iterate through it and get, set or delete the text. Using a set (unordered) or a List (ordered) you are not able to identify it by a specific identifier (name, ID, ...), but using a Map you put an identifier as a key and TextField as a value pair into it which allows to get the unique TextField for a given identifier.

Comment: I was thinking about the way to go would be to use a list, I'll give it a try and see how it turns out, thanks.